# Get unique lines

Tags: linux, bash, awk, unique, delimiter

I'm creating graph in graphViz and I need every connection to be display only once, how to transform this input using linux commands?

INPUT

```
aa -- bb[label=xyz]
ab -- bb[label=yzx]
aa -- bb[label=zxy]
ac -- ab[label=xyz]
bb -- aa[label=xzy]
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
aa -- bb[label=xyz]
ab -- bb[label=yzx]
ac -- ab[label=xyz]
```

so `aa -- bb` equals to `bb -- aa` and needs to be removed.

I tried `sort -k1,2 -u -t[` bot it didnt work with `[` delimiter and don't know how to check for "reverse" entries ("xx -- yy" = "yy -- xx")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[[]| -- ' '!a[$1,$2]++&&!a[$2,$1]' file
aa -- bb[label=xyz]
ab -- bb[label=yzx]
ac -- ab[label=xyz]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specifify [ as the delimiter this way:

```
sort -k2 -u -t'['
```

Does that give you what you need ?

Comment: This won't work as it doesn't treat `aa -- bb` and `bb -- aa` as equal.

Comment: OK. Need to think some more.

Comment: I tried it too but sort doesn't accept any "special" char as delimiter except alphanumeric characters this way

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea (not tested, but should be close):

```
sed -e 's/[[].*// -e 's/-- //' input.txt |
  awk '{ if ((e[$1$2] != 1) && (e[$2$1] != 1))
         { print $1, $2
           e[$1$2] = e[$2$1] = 1
         }
       }'
```

The `sed ...` bit strips out the `--` and the `[label...]` portions, since you don't seem to care about them, then `awk` keeps track of which pairs have been seen in either order and only prints them if they haven't been seen yet.

Comment: It will be difficult to be simplest and cleaner than [sudo_O response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15664062/465183) =)